# Paste the repeating values from another excel sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In `sheet2`, I have the table like this:

[image]

In `sheet1`, I have the table like this:

[image]

My goal is to fill the `price` column in sheet1 using some formulas in excel.

Of course, the expected output of `sheet1` should be

[image]

But, in my actual data, there are so many rows so that I cannot fill the `price` column. So, I want to do this using some formulas in excel.

Comment: `INDEX` / `MATCH` will do that job - you will find a lot of tutorials

Comment: Or VLOOKUP or XLOOKUP.  Heck even SUMIF will do it.

Comment: Or remove duplicates (Data -> Data Tools -> Remove Duplicates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created such a Sheet1:

[image]

I have created such a Sheet2, where the value of B2 is equal to `=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!A$2:B$5,2,FALSE)`, and this is the result:

[image]